# PHPUnit: Filter only for one testsuite

Tags: configuration, filter, phpunit, test-suite

In PHPUnit it is posible to organize the tests in different testsuites:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="Bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="zf2sandbox">
            <directory>./AlbumTest</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Furthermore you can define filters like

```
<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">/var/www/sandbox/zf2sandbox/module/Album/src/Album/</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Now I'd like to combine these two fetaures. It's not allowed to put a `filter` tag into a `testsuite` (the filter is just ignored).

```
<phpunit bootstrap="Bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="zf2sandbox">
            <directory>./AlbumTest</directory>
            <filter>
                <whitelist>
                    <directory suffix=".php">/var/www/sandbox/zf2sandbox/module/Album/src/Album/</directory>
                </whitelist>
            </filter>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Is there another way to define filters (whilists, blacklists etc.) for each `testsuite`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding the `filter` inside the `testsuite` tag, because in your example it is in the `testsuites` tag. ie:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="Bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="zf2sandbox">
            <directory>./AlbumTest</directory>
            <filter>
                <whitelist>
                    <directory suffix=".php">/var/www/sandbox/zf2sandbox/module/Album/src/Album/</directory>
                </whitelist>
            </filter>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: I don't think it is supported by PHPUnit, also see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672946/codecoverage-with-phpunit-not-generating)